# Accessing JSON parsed object

Tags: javascript, json

So here is my JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/",
        type:"POST",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            var token = $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content');

            if (token) {
                  return xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token);
            }
        },
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },error:function(){ 
            console.log("error!!!!");
        }
    }); 

});
```

And this is what I get in my console:

```
Object { all_creations: "[{"id":"2","user_id":"2","title":"D…" }
```

But now I'd like to do something like:

```
console.log(data.user_id)
```

But this return nothing..

Same for:

```
console.log(data['all_creations'].user_id)
console.log(data['all_creations'][0].user_id)
console.log(data[0].user_id)
```

...

I am using laravel5 btw and this JSON object is return by the toJson() function. (if this is any help)

I know this question has already been answered millions times but for some reason I cannot get it work on my project... I am not a pro in Javascript or anything related to it like JSON. Ajax, JSON remain for me a source of intense pain. I hope to get it one day... seriously ^^

Comment: `JSON.parse(data.all_creations)[0].user_id` - it seems like the server isn't returning what you expect, though, so perhaps you should look into that first.

Comment: \o/ I almost want to cry... I spent an entire day on this. And you answer in less than a minute. THANK YOU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anything, this is a rough guide to how you can access your data:

```
Object { all_creations: "[{"id":"2","user_id":"2","title":"D…" }
^^^^^^^^                                                       ^
```

The marked areas indicate that `data` is a standard object, so it has already been parsed.

```
Object { all_creations: "[{"id":"2","user_id":"2","title":"D…" }
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The inner portion says that `data.all_creations` is a property that contains a string value.

```
Object { all_creations: "[{"id":"2","user_id":"2","title":"D…" }
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The string value itself seems to contain a JSON encoded value, so you would need to parse that first:

```
var creations = JSON.parse(data.all_creations);
```

Then, from the string value you can see it contains an array with an object as the first element.

```
alert(creations[0].user_id) // 2
```

Comment: I understand much better than I ever did ! Thank you very much @jack

Answer (score 0):

I feel like your best bet here would be to test it in Chrome and use the F12 developer tools to see what is coming back from the server. Maybe check the request in the Network tab or try to figure out the proper way to retrieve the user_id in the console.

If confused take a look at some F12 Chrome developer tools tutorials.